# Get a specific product by id in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know how I can get access to a product by id in WooCommerce? I'd like to display the product attributes for the specific product on my homepage however I can only find shortcode example of this.

Is their any way to display the product by a certain id like so:

```
$product = PRODUCT WITH ID OF 10;
$product->get_attribute('pa_location');
```

Any idea how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use  [Class WC_Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)

```
$product = new WC_Product(10);  
$product->get_attribute('pa_location');
```